# How to use pywinauto

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am trying to automate an app that i think is using java as backend. But so far i have managed to print out the identifiers. i just dont know what to do from there?

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend='win32').connect(best_match='RuneLite')

app.RuneLite.print_control_identifiers()
```

> Control Identifiers:
>
> SunAwtFrame - 'RuneLite'    (L49, T321, R851, B929) ['RuneLite',
> 'RuneLiteSunAwtFrame', 'SunAwtFrame'] child_window(title="RuneLite",
> class_name="SunAwtFrame")    |     | SunAwtCanvas - ''    (L53, T348,
> R847, B925)    | ['SunAwtCanvas', 'RuneLiteSunAwtCanvas',
> 'SunAwtCanvas0', 'SunAwtCanvas1', 'RuneLiteSunAwtCanvas0',
> 'RuneLiteSunAwtCanvas1']    | child_window(class_name="SunAwtCanvas")
> |    |     |    | SunAwtCanvas - ''    (L53, T348, R847, B925)    |
> | ['SunAwtCanvas2', 'RuneLiteSunAwtCanvas2']    |    |
> child_window(class_name="SunAwtCanvas")    |     | SunAwtCanvas - ''
> (L53, T348, R847, B925)    | ['SunAwtCanvas2',
> 'RuneLiteSunAwtCanvas2']    | child_window(class_name="SunAwtCanvas")

i just dont know how i can make it click a button or anything else